# Why is the destructuring assignment not working properly?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I was trying to get the `x` and `y` value from `obj.coords`, but the value is not updated using destructuring assignment.

```js
let obj = { name: 'test', coords: [0, 0] }
let x = 0, y = 0

obj = { ...obj, coords: [12, 16] }

// not working
[x, y] = obj.coords

console.log('coords:', x, y)
```

I tried assign them one by one, it works:

```js
let obj = { name: 'test', coords: [0, 0] }
let x = 0, y = 0

obj = { ...obj, coords: [12, 16] }

// works
x = obj.coords[0]
y = obj.coords[1]

console.log('coords:', x, y)
```

Is there a reason for that? Or is it some kind of bug?

Comment: Add a semicolon to the line before array destructuring. Otherwise, it is interpreted as `obj = { ...obj, coords: [12, 16] }[x, y] = obj.coords`.

Comment: There is nothing destructive here, e.g. information loss. It’s not called “destructive assignment”. It’s called “destructuring”, because you’re extracting things from a structure.

Comment: One of the few gotchas for not using the "optional" semicolons.